# How to get all content of website from google cache?

Tags: blogspot

My gmail account was hacked today, and I can't login or request new password anymore. And I lost all content in my blogspot too.
I looked around and found it was stored in google cache. But I had more than 200 articles, and I need to go through more than 200 urls to copy all content.
Is there any methods can help me retries all content from google cache?

Comment: This sounds like you should be talking to Google customer service, not us.

Comment: plz consult Google password recovery centre

Comment: There’s [a good question on webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/33346/recovering-a-lost-website-with-no-backup) about this very subject.

Comment: I send request to Google center right after I can't login my account. But I'm not sure they can give it back. Hacker even changed my sub email, my phone number, and shutdown my blog.

Answer (score 0):

- A [Web Crawler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) could help you to retrieve many pages of information.
- Also, maybe you could use [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/web.php) to retrieve some lost information.
- Another tip: the [google advanced search](http://www.google.com/advanced_search) could help you too. In particular, the *site or domain* param.

---

**Update:** Maybe this script can do all work for you: **[Retrieving Google’s Cache for a Whole Website](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2008/10/02/retrieving-googles-cache-for-a-whole-website/)**

Comment: Thank you. I will try any methods no bring it back. I will report to you when I get a result.